# How to add Replace (mysql) function in view query condition field

Tags: 7, database, views

I am using EntityReference Autocomplete with filter by entity reference view. And I want to ignore space in search filed.

For example, column `username` in DB has value `first name` it should popup when user types `first` or `firstname`. To achieve this I wrote `hook_views_query_alter` to change the condition, I would like to pass the condition as `REPLACE(username, ' ', '') LIKE '%firstname%'`.

Even if I set field value in condition to `REPLACE(username, ' ', '')` its getting changed to `REPLACEusername`. Even I tried running the query separately, like below in node,

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
              ->fields('n', array('title'))
              ->condition('type', 'article', '=')
              ->condition('REPLACE(n.title, \' \', \'\')', $category, 'LIKE')
```

When I output query prints like below,

```
    SELECT n.title AS title FROM {node} n WHERE (type = 'article') AND (REPLACEn.title LIKE '%articleone%' ESCAPE '\\')
```

How can I set it correctly? Is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `condition` is what you want, rather [`expression`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7). And then, to use that expression as a condition, you might need to use [`havingCondition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AhavingCondition/7)-- but I'm not sure, test it out. Also note that you need `%` for a wildcard matching in SQL, so you might have to do `->havingCondition('title', '%' . $category . '%', 'LIKE');`.

So, your final code might look something like this:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->addExpression('REPLACE(n.title, \' \', \'\')', 'title')
  ->condition('type', 'article', '=')
  ->havingCondition('title', '%' . $category . '%', 'LIKE');
```